# In Java: how to 'pickup' an element of a container and 'place' it in another container?

Tags: javascript, java, containers, text-based

I'm exploring how to create a text-based game, and I was tinkering around with moving between rooms. I have this part down and a very elaborate map created where you can type, "go north" etc. The only thing is that the game is very dry, and I wanted to incorporate items. To make the rooms I did this:

```js
     var rooms = {
        "room0":{
               "description": "description here",
               "directions":{
               "direction": "newRoom"
               }
         }
     }
```

So, I was thinking if I made a separate element called "items" and then list the items in that room, the way I did with "directions". I wrote this code to add items to the player inventory:

```js
     function grabItem(item){
        if(inventory.length < 12 && rooms[currentRoom].items[item] !== undefined) {
            inventory.append(item);

            //INSERT CODE HERE TO REMOVE THE ITEM FROM THE ROOM
        }
      }
```

SO! The big question is, what method can I use to remove an individual item?

Answer (score 0):

```js
     function grabItem(item){
        if(inventory.length < 12 && rooms[currentRoom].items[item] !== undefined) {
            inventory.append(rooms[currentRoom].items[item]);

            rooms[currentRoom].items[item] = undefined;
        }
      }
```

NB `java!==javascript`